# Django - additional(not override) custom models methods to User

Tags: python, django

I dont want to change default auth model.

I just want to add additional methods for User like this:

```
def update_first_name(self, first_name):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.save()
```

This is a bad example, but I want such functionality.  This should be only additional, and should not discard any other available methods for User.

Comment: i would go for UserProfile and write there any method i want. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Answer (score 2):

Create a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for `User` and add your methods there.

```
class ProxyUser(User):
  def do_something(self, ...):
     ...

  class Meta:
    proxy = True
```

Comment: Then, how should I get user object first, User.objects.get or ProxyUser.objects.get ?? I want to use User.objects.get because there may be a project where User.objetcs.get already being used and I dont want to change all.

Answer (score 1):

To add new functionalities to `User` class is by defining a Proxy Model.
It means `creating a proxy for the original model.`

```
class UserExtend(User):
        class Meta:
            proxy= True

        def update_first_name(self, first_name):
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.save()
```